# Python: Rolling Correlation Plot Results in "ValueError: could not convert string to float:"

Tags: python, matplotlib, correlation

I am trying to plot the rolling correlation of two stock prices. This function used to work but for some reason, it now is not working. I am getting the an error when trying to plot using pd.rolling_corr

For example, I download AAPL and TSLA stock data, and then get their adjusted prices into two series. I then try to run a rolling correlation plot.  I am getting the following error:

"ValueError: could not convert string to float: '2013-01-02"

```
import numpy as np
randn = np.random.randn
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pylab as pylab
%matplotlib inline
from yahoo_finance import Share

start = '2013-01-01'
end = '2015-01-01'
TSLA=pd.DataFrame(Share('TSLA').get_historical(start, end))
TSLA=TSLA.set_index('Date')
AAPL=pd.DataFrame(Share('AAPL').get_historical(start, end))
AAPL=AAPL.set_index('Date')

TSLA_px=TSLA['Adj_Close']
AAPL_px=AAPL['Adj_Close']

rolling_correlation = pd.rolling_corr(TSLA_px, AAPL_px, 60)
plt.plot(rolling_correlation)
plt.xlabel('Day')
plt.ylabel('60-day Rolling Correlation')
```

Comment: Could it be that you're * importing `pandas`, yet calling `pd.DataFrame` and `pd.rolling_corr`? Try `import pandas as pd` instead. Even if it doesn't fix your problem, it's much better practice.

Comment: Thank you Lanery, good catch! Late night coding...doesn't solve the problem but you are right!

Answer (score 1):

Stupid noob mistake...date from the yahoo data comes in as a string and needs to be converted to date.

```
TSLA['Date']=pd.to_datetime(TSLA['Date'])
```

Comment: Good call. I had just revisited your question and made the same realization. FWIW, `pandas_datareader` may serve you better than the `yahoo_finance` package, http://pandas-datareader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remote_data.html.